# How can I add transition effects to my LibGdx game?

Tags: libgdx

I'm making splash screen for my game, i want to display the logo and Name with different Transition effects. I'm a noob here, having no idea of scenes stage n all. If scenes and stages are required,  a simple explanation with code would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different screens for the logo and the name, and create a transition between them.
For that, you can use the libgdx-transitions library for creating e.g. some alpha-fading, or sliding transitions:

https://github.com/digital-thinking/libgdx-transitions

Here in the test case you can see how it works:

https://github.com/digital-thinking/libgdx-transitions/wiki

Basically, you create transitions and then you can change them before you change the screen.

Or you could do this on a single screen using the Universal Tween Engine.
With that, you can create a Timeline where you (for example) change the alpha levels of pictures of the logo and the name (make the pictures appear and disappear).

Comment: I could get fading effect by changing alpha component of batch used to draw logo, using setColor method.
For transition to apply on name, i could get Zoom in effect by scaling the font. I found this quite simple.
Also, i tried running the test case but it terminated with a runtime error showing some sort of IllegalAccess in Logs.